# Redirect location.href doesn't work

Tags: android, redirect

The redirect at the end of the snippet works on Desktop machine but not on Mobile Phone (Android device)

```
var ajax1 = XMLHttpRequest();  
var sigData = encodeURIComponent(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));  
ajax1.open("POST", './post.php');  
ajax1.send(sigText.innerHTML);  
$('#debug').html(canvas);
document.location.href='step2.php?xidx="+xidx+"';
```

Comment: Those quotes seem messed up...

Comment: Instead of `'step2.php?xidx="+xidx+"'`, could you possibly do `'step2.php?xidx='+xidx` or better yet `'step2.php?xidx='+encodeURIComponent(xidx)`?

Comment: What do you mean by "works"?   Does it redirect to the wrong location or not redirect at all?  What do you see in the developer console?  What is `sigText`?  What is `canvas`?

Comment: sigText is a string, and the Redirect do : nothing....